# transfer the input data in the dynamic element to the react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have code done where I can dynamically create a component with images and save the state.

The state is captured in this array:

```
const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([0]);
const dynamicLogos = (id, url) => {
    setUploadLogos((el) => {
      let ArrayLogos = [...el]; 
      ArrayLogos[id] = url; 
      return ArrayLogos 
    })
};
```

And in general, the code works as it should, but also. inside the `SimpleComponent` component, there is an input where I want to specify the data and save this state:

```
<input type="number" value={{}} onChange={() => {}} />
```

Please, can you tell me how to do this? Thank you!

Here's the hollow code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SimpleComponent } from './SimpleComponent ';

function App() {

  const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([0]);
  const dynamicLogos = (id, url) => {
        setUploadLogos((el) => {
          let ArrayLogos = [...el]; 
          ArrayLogos[id] = url; 
          return ArrayLogos 
        })
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setUploadLogos([...UploadLogos, UploadLogos.length])
        }
      >
        Add
      </button>
      {UploadLogos.map((logo, i) => (
        <SimpleComponent
          key={i}
          id={i}
          Image={logo}
          setImage={dynamicLogos}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**SimpleComponent.jsx**

```
export function SimpleComponent({id, Image, setImage}) {
    return (
      <>
        <input 
            type="file" accept="image/*"
            onChange={event => { if (!event.target.files[0]) return; setImage(id, URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])) }} 
        />
        <img src={Image} /> 
        <input type="number" value={{}} onChange={() => {}} />
      </>   
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number input in `SimpleComponent` is something you want to also store in the `UploadLogos` state array in the parent component then I suggest the following refactor.

- Update the state to hold an array of objects with `id`, `src`, and `data` properties. The `id` will be a generated GUID, `src` is the inputed file source, and `data` is the state for the other input.

  ```
  function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const addData = () =>
      setData((data) =>
        data.concat({
          id: nanoid(),
          src: "",
          data: ""
        })
      );

    const updateData = (id, key, value) =>
      setData((data) =>
        data.map((el) => (el.id === id ? { ...el, [key]: value } : el))
      );

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={addData}>Add</button>
        <br />
        {data.map((item) => (
          <SimpleComponent key={item.id} item={item} updateData={updateData} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  ```
- Update `SimpleComponent` to pass the appropriate `item.src` and `item.data` properties, and use the `updateData` callback to enqueue state updates.

  ```
  function SimpleComponent({ item, updateData }) {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={(event) => {
            if (!event.target.files[0]) return;
            updateData(
              item.id,
              "src",
              URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
            );
          }}
        />
        <img alt="Simple preview" src={item.src} />
        <input
          type="number"
          value={item.data}
          onChange={(e) => updateData(item.id, "data", e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
  ```

[image]